# Pull request on a branch which got cherry picked commits merged

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-cherry-pick

I initiated a feature development in BranchA, but I included some 'clean up' and 'tweaking' commits on it.

In the middle of the process 'tweaking' commits needed to be merged into the master (by doing a pull request) so I created a BranchB with some new commits and cherry picked some of the commits done in BranchA.
BranchB was merged with no conflicts.

My question is: How to handle the BranchA pull request?
Is it safe to submit BranchA even if some of its commits were already merged? If not, how to go through this situation?

[image: Situation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase branch A on B: only the commits not cherry-picked should be there.

```
 B--B--B--B--A'--A'--A' (A)
           \
         m--M--m--m (master)
```

Then rebase A on top of master:

```
git rebase --onto master B A
```

That will rebase all commits after B HEAD, up to A HEAD (included).

```
 B--B--B--B (B)
           \
         m--M--m--m (master)  
                   \
                    A''--A''--A'' (A)
```

From there, you can make your pull-request.

Comment: I did it like this: `git checkout master && git fetch upstream && git merge upstream/master && git checkout BranchA && git rebase BranchB && git rebase master`